# What is the function to get options of the parent site of a multisite network?

Tags: multisite, options

I need to set options of a specific plugin at the parent site of a network and use those settings globally to override each site, unless set to `false`.

Neither `get_option()` or `get_site_option()` does the task. They just return values relative to the current site. All the solutions I have encountered are methods to use database query with `$wpdb->get_results()`but I figure the mighty WP must have a built-in method to do this task.

**Example use**

- Plugin setting to display ad banner set to `true` at parent site
- The plugin is available across the network to insert banners but cannot be disabled because the condition only accepts the parent value unless set to `false`

**code scenario (not an actual WP function)**

```php
if( get_parent_site_option('adbanners')['show_banners'] == 1 ) {
  showAds();
}else
if( get_site_option('adbanners')['show_banners'] == 1 ) {
  showAds();
}else{
  // ads disabled on this current site
}
```

**Is there a WP function to do this without the direct DB query method?**

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *the parent site of a network*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the function to achieve the goal - `get_blog_option($blogId, $optionKey)`

https://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_blog_option